# Find what paths are required for open_basedir?

Tags: php, php-fpm, apache2, open-basedir

We have a server (running PHP-FPM 7.4 on Apache) that hosts various scripts, frameworks and applications like DokuWiki. It's grown to a pretty complex beast. We would like to apply an [`open_basedir`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir) restriction. Just setting a best guess `open_basedir` is bound to cause problems. Is there a way to find out the minimal set of the paths that are actually required?

If an `open_basedir` restriction could be made non-fatal, for instance, so that it logs warnings instead of errors, we could monitor these. But I found no way to make open_basedir non-fatal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open_basedir` can not be put into something similar to selinux "permissive mode", where would-be-denied accesses are logged but not really blocked.

My best advice is to use `strace` to look at `openat` system call from `httpd` or `php-fpm`. You can do that at runtime via the following command:

`strace -f -e openat -p "$(pidof httpd php-fpm)"`

To save `strace` output to a file, add `-o /my/file.txt`